# Java Grammar To Class decleration

Tags: java, grammar

I am going through past papers for my exams in May and i'm not sure how I would answer the following question:

```
The following grammar describes a simple language of arithmetic expressions:

exp -> lp exp rp | exp op exp | number
op -> plus | minus | times

The symbols, lp, rp, plus, minus and times refer to the lexemes (, ), +, - and *
respectively and the symbol number refers to any non-negative integer
Provide a declaration for a Java class that could be used to store parse trees for this
grammar. The methods of the class do not have to be declared.
```

I understand what the grammar is e.g. I can use either a plus, minus or times for the operaters and I could have something like (5) which is lp exp rp. To convert it into a class decleration that's where I get lost. I've gone through the teaching content and this is very lightly covered. Any guidance would be grealty appreciated.

Comment: Since the question specifically says you don't need methods, it's asking for the data model. Describe the fields needed for a node in this AST.

Comment: Would that mean just creating the different types of lexemes then?

Comment: I think it's asking about the actual node object, but that's not entirely clear.